# Modificar o cancelar una alarma con pycom

Tags: python

Tengo una clase que tiene un `__init__` con esta línea de código:

```
self.__alarm = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, self.time_LoRa, periodic=True)
```

Básicamente hace que cada X segundos (definidos en `time_LoRa`) salte una alarma.

Hay un momento de mi código (en otro punto) en el que me interesa modificar este tiempo. Para eso tengo esto esta función de mi misma clase,

```
def time_LoRa_modify(self, new_time):
    print('NEW TIME',new_time)
    self.time_LoRa = new_time
    self.__alarm = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, new_time, periodic=True)
```

Mi sensación es que ahora se ejecutan DOS alarmas, la inicializada en el `__init__` y la nueva, ¿Es posible que esto esté pasando? De ser así, ¿como cancelaría la primera? Pues como digo, lo que quiero es modificar la que ya tengo, no crear una nueva.

Adjunto la clase entera por si hiciera falta,

```
from machine import Timer
import config
import ustruct

class Clock:

    # Inicializo. Establezco los segundos de acción y ejecuto _secodnnhanfler
    def __init__(self):
        self.time_LoRa = config.time_LoRa
        # Ejecución de las alarmas (funciones)
        self.__alarm = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, self.time_LoRa, periodic=True)

    # Función para modificar remotamente el tiempo de envío de datos por LoRa.
    def time_LoRa_modify(self, new_time):
        print('NEW TIME',new_time)
        self.time_LoRa = new_time
        self.__alarm = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, new_time, periodic=True)
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: El título de la pregunta es engañoso pues realmente el problema no está en modificar un atributo de la clase (lo cual no tiene misterio a través de `self`) sino en la cancelación/modificación de la alarma. Sugiero cambiar el título a "Modificar o cancelar una alarma con pycom" (poniendo de paso el nombre de la biblioteca o framework que uses, que he supuesto que es pycom pero no lo mencionas)

Comment: Ningún problema, pensaba que era un problema de clases genérico y por eso lo puse así.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final conseguí que funcione de la siguiente manera:

```
from machine import Timer
import config
import ustruct

class Clock:

    # Inicializo.
    def __init__(self):
        self.time_LoRa = config.time_LoRa

   def set_clock_alarms(self):
        self.alarm_LoRa = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, self.time_LoRa, periodic=True)

    # Función para modificar remotamente el tiempo de envío de datos por LoRa.
    def time_LoRa_modify(self, new_time):
        self.alarm_LoRa.cancel()
        self.time_LoRa = new_time
        self.set_clock_alarms()
```

El cambio es que ya no inicializo la alarma en el `__init__` sino en una función destinada a ello `set_clock_alarms()`. Y a esto se le suma, que no se puede modificar las alarmas sino que debemos cancelarlas y crear una nueva que lo hago en `time_LoRa_modify`.

**Muchas gracias a @Dante S. por la ayuda.**

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que escribí NO pude probarlo ya que no pude instalar el modulo. Sin embargo, encontré la documentacion adecuada aqui: https://docs.pycom.io/firmwareapi/pycom/machine/timer/

Y encontré que hay una forma de cancelar el Timer.

En la documentacion dice:

> Currently, there are 2 classes that support interrupts; the Alarm and Pin classes. Both classes provide the .callback() method that enables the interrupt and registers the given handler.

Otra seccion dice:

> alarm.callback(handler, [arg=None])

> Specify a callback handler for the alarm. If set to None, the alarm will be disabled.

Aparentemente, hay que usar ese metodo para que sea posible cancelar la alarma.

```
def time_LoRa_modify(self, new_time):
    print('NEW TIME',new_time)
    self.time_LoRa = new_time
    self.__alarm.callback(None)
    self.__alarm = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, new_time, periodic=True)
```

Por lo que vi no parece haber una forma de modificar la alarma.
Por favor, comunicame si funcionó.

Comment: Si ese código que has puesto funciona, supongo que también debería funcionar el hacer simplemente `Timer.Alarm.cancel(self.__alarm)`

Comment: No me refería a eso, pero gracias igual Abulafia. Aun así, no funcionaría, ya que no usa el método `callback`. Ya probé con algo similar antes y me dijo que no funcionó.

Comment: ¡Hola, al final lo he conseguido solucionar! Efectivamente hay que cancelar la alarma con `alarm.cancel`. Lo que hice (no se si es la mejor solución) es no inicializar las alarmas en el `__init__`, sino tener una función separada para está acción, de esta manera después de cancelar la alarma, la vuelvo a llamar con los parámetros renovados y ya funciona bien, ahora añadiré una respuesta por si alguien le hiciera falta. ¡GRACIAS!